# Binding 2 instances of the same control to different properties

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

I have a main VM. It instanciate 2 user controls of the same type.

Each control should be bound to a different property of the VM to display its details (and update if it changes).

Would you know how to do so?

I can't figure out how to tell at the instanciation wich property it should hook to... (meaning: I obviously can't pass the property in input at the instanciation)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you:

```
<StackPanel>
    <MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding Property1}" />
    <MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding Property2}" />
</StackPanel>
```